# Using python lambda function map when adding elements to a set

Tags: python, lambda

I try to run

```
 lst = ['ab','cd','cdc','cd','ab','abcd']
 g = set()
 list(map(lambda x:g.add(x),lst))
```

Then the set g contains correct elements

```
>>>print(g)
{'abcd', 'ab', 'cdc', 'cd'}
```

But if I remove the list conversion

```
lst = ['ab','cd','cdc','cd','ab','abcd']
g = set()
map(lambda x:g.add(x),lst)
```

Then g is empty

```
>>>print(g)
set()
```

Why does this happen

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but: rather than passing `g.add` to `map()`, consider simply doing `g = set(lst)`, or even `g = {'ab','cd','cdc','cd','ab','abcd'}`.

Comment: The lambda expression is just an expensive wrapper around `g.add` that doesn't gain you anything.  `map(g.add, lst)` works the same.

Comment: do **not** use `map` for side-effects